# "drug of choice" or "choice of drug"

Tags: word-usage

I came across a sentence while reading the Angels and Demons of Dan Brown;

*Their drug of choice was a potent intoxicant they called hashish.*

If I constructed the sentence from the scratch It would be;

*Their drug choice was a potent intoxicant they called hashish.* or
*Their choice of drug was a potent intoxicant they called hashish.*

Is the original sentence true? If it so, why?

Comment: First things first.  You run into people in the street but you come across or stumble across sentences in book.  I believe both choices work but drug choice works better for headings and titles. For example:  DRUG CHOICE AMONGST TEENAGERS.  A study about....etc.

Comment: ...but I understand that among users and recovery specialists the term "drug of choice" is used, which may be one of *several* drugs that are being abused. It's an idiomatic phrase, not a "Use of English" one, and that's why it is in the book.

Comment: This distinction was [asked about on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217994/) some years ago (in the context of ***choice of ride / ride of choice***). In practice, ***drug of choice*** and ***choice of drug*** are "equivalent" in the cited context here, even though we can obviously point out that *strictly speaking*, one version refers to a specific ***choice***, whereas the other refers to a specific ***drug***. That's just a hypothetical distinction with no significance in the real world. But *Their drug choice* is at least a *slightly* "marked, unusual" choice.

Comment: By "idiomatic" I meant *within a certain subculture*.